# ReactJS - Can't import component

Tags: javascript, import, routes, reactjs, react-router

I'm brand new to ReactJS.  I'm developing a little single page app and I'm just trying to create my components to import within my main component.

**TestComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

export class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">Test Component</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Inside my **main.jsx** I've imported this component calling

```
import TestComponent from './components/TestComponent.jsx'
```

Then I've tried to call my component for a specific route:

```
render(
    (<Router history={history}>
        <Route path="/" component={NavMenu}>
            <IndexRoute component={Index}/>
            <Route path="test" component={TestComponent}></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>),
    document.getElementById('main')
)
```

I've not got any errors from the console, but I don't see my component. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The import syntax without curly braces is for importing default exports, not for importing named exports.

Make your component the default export:

**TestComponent.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

export default class TestComponent extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="content">Test Component</div>
        )
    }
}
```

Alternatively you should be able to import it as it is with the following import statement:

```
import { TestComponent } from './components/TestComponent.jsx'
```

You might want to read up on ES6 modules (e.g. in [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html)) if you want to use ES6 in your React code.

Comment: the second one was what i was searching for, thank you also for the link!

Comment: You're right man, I've read the React docs and they explain the same recommendation. I'll follow this approach, thank you again!

Comment: Why you use `export default`? Can I write two classes in one file and then call each of them in another file?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to include semicolons after the import statements too. you might get away with a browser (or environment like Node) reading the code in some cases, but the import function runs right into your export in this code.

Answer (score 0):

.js should have the first letter capital. Else import will not take place.

Comment: File names are case sensitive, but that doesn't mean they need the capital.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).